# Update the value of a Spring bean property using SpEL

Tags: java, spring, expression

I'm creating a web app using Spring 3 and would like to harness the power of the Spring Expression Language but have run into a problem.  I need to set the value of a property on one of my beans to the result of a method call on another bean.  I know I can do this but the issue is that the result of that method call may change after the bean is initialized and I need that property to reflect the change.  For instance:

```
<beans>
 ...
 <bean name="guestList" class="java.util.ArrayList"></bean>

 <bean name="party" class="some.custom.class.Party">
  <property name="numberOfGuests" value="#{guestList.size()}" />
 </bean>
 ...
</beans>
```

From what I can tell, the `numberOfGuests` field is set the first time the `party` field is accessed.  But after the `party` field is accessed, the number of guests may change and I need the `numberOfGuests` field to reflect that.  Is there a way to reinitialize the `numberOfGuests` field within my app whenever I need the value updated?

This is just an example and accessing the `guestList` bean directly will not work for my specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set your scope to prototype then each time Spring loads your bean it should recalculate the guest list size:

```
 <bean name="party" class="some.custom.class.Party" scope="prototype">
```

So, `party` becomes prototype but `guestList` can stay a singleton (which is the default scope).

There's a catch though: if you have another bean, like `partyHost` (which is a singleton), and it gets injected with `party` (which is a prototype), `partyHost` will never get another instance of `party`, since `partyHost` is a singleton, and only gets dependencies injected into it once. So for this to work, all of your beans that need the updated guest list size, and all of the beans that reference them, etc. must be prototypes too.

Either that, or you'd have to ask Spring directly via their API. If you use the API, you could call it any time you want and get a new instance of the prototype bean, and therefore the updated guest list size.

```
applicationContext.getBean("myPrototype");
```

However it's better to avoid the Spring API if you can. Typically developers don't want to be coupled to a DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

The example of #{guestlist.size()} only sets the initial value of the property, not the policy for keeping it up-to-date. Assuming you're not using lazy loading, Spring instantiates Spring managed beans from the application context at startup. From that point on it's up to the developer to handle updating property values.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the simplest to do would be to inject the list (`guestList`) to the bean and call its `.size()` method manually from Java code everytime you need `numberOfGuests`, i.e.:

```
package some.custom.class;

public class Party {
   private List<?> guestList;
   // getter & setters

   public int getNumberOfGuests() {
     return guestList!=null ? guestList.size() : 0;
   }

}
```

and...

```
<bean name="party" class="some.custom.class.Party">
  <property name="guestList" ref="guestList"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: this is definitely the simplest (and preferred!) way to do it, but the OP said "This is just an example and accessing the guestList bean directly will not work for my specific situation."

Comment: You're right. Point taken. We definitely need some more information then. What's wrong with the direct access to the `guestList` bean?